# Is using a non-ptr at std::map's value a good practice

Tags: c++, stl

I wanted to defined a map like
   `std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_set<int>>`
or
   `std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<std::unordered_set<int>>>`

I am not sure which one is better.

I cannot see if the first one has any problem. In terms of [Does std::map::iterator return a copy of value or a value itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377434/does-stdmapiterator-return-a-copy-of-value-or-a-value-itself)
the first is safe because the access of each set of a map should also be of reference type.

If so, which one is better?

Comment: It really depends what you want. There's no "problem" with either of them, but they mean different things.

Comment: I guess the only thing that the second type can do is releasing the memory of a set and passing it to others. If the map is the only owner of all the sets, functionally they should be same. But I am not sure in terms of the time/space performance, is there any con/pro of each definition?

Comment: Both look good, but unless I have a good reason to add the complexity of a pointer, even a safe one, I shy away from it.

Comment: I recommend keeping it simple until you know there's a reason to do otherwise.  Using the additional indirection of `unique_ptr` is unnecessary if you're not sure why you'd want it.  Historically, many of the reasons that might have caused you to choose the `unique_ptr` approach are now solved by move-semantics.

Comment: They both do the essentiallysame thing. The first one is better because its less complicated. In either one the `std::unordered_set` uses a *pointer* internally and stores its data on the heap (free-store). `STL` containers are basically smart pointers managing their data through *pointers*.

Comment: @paddy, I think what you mean is 'most of the reasons... choose a UNIQUE pointer are now ... by move-semantics'?

Comment: @JoeC Cheers, fair enough.  I had time to edit my comment.  Although, it feels weird because `std::unique_ptr` was added at the same time as move semantics.  But yes, the concept of unique pointers itself was around for much longer and that's what I was getting at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer `std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_set<int>>`.  Most C++ containers consist of a kind of 'header' data structure, containing pointers to the actual data (e.g. an std::vector is simply a class containing a few pointers to the actual underlying 'array' data).  This 'header' data structure is typically relatively small, so if you would store an `std::unique_ptr` to it, the actual overhead of the memory allocation (both in CPU-time overhead and memory overhead) will be relatively large.

On the other hand, if your problem requires you to efficiently see that an entry in the `std::unordered_map` is 'empty', and/or you will have lots of these empty entries in the map, using an `std::unique_ptr` might be more efficient.

Also note that containers like `std::set` and `std::map` have a relatively large memory overhead.  Consider using `std:vector` instead of `std::set` if the set would only contain a few elements.  Looping over a small vector to check for duplicates might be more efficient that using the hashing logic of an `std::set` (because the memory locality of the `std::vector` will make more efficient use of the processors memory cache, see presentation of Chandler Carruth on CPPCON2014, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHNmRkzxHWs).

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your utility function if you want to know what is best.

What are you optimizing?  As the question stands, I can just say that personally, I prefer less typing so `std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_set<int>>` is best.  But, that's likely not your utility function.

If you are concerned about performance, then if you use `std::unique_ptr` the extra level of indirection will cost you, an allocation, a hop and a cache load.  If you were sharing sets between collections, then a `std::shared_ptr` would cost a hop but maintain consistency and lower overall memory.

If your sets are smallish, frequently empty, or updated often, it might make sense to use `std::unordered_map<int,std::set<int>>`

Under some use cases you could also combine the map and set keys and just use `std::unordered_set<std::pair<int, int> >`

Or `std::tuple<int, int>` if supported.

Comment: My concern was more about runtime efficiency. In terms of all above answers, they should be the same about performance. Than the first one gives us less typing.

Comment: @JoeC you should refine your question to include your utility function, and state your use case, but in the meantime, see if my edit helps you

Answer (score 0):

`std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<std::unordered_set<int>>>`

 this looks really redundant. the whole point of `unique_ptr` is that when it gets out of scope - it deletes and destroy what it points at.

 if your map's value is some pointer that needs deletion - go ahead. but your value is `std::unordered_set` that will get destroyed and deleted even without the pointer.
so you basically add extra creation and deletion on the smart pointer without adding any extra functionality.